# A question about installing Ubuntu by VMware

Tags: system-installation

Here is a question after I installed the Ubuntu by VMware.

After I finished the installing process, I found that my Ubuntu is just a "terminal" without a GUI.

Specs:

- Windows 7
- Memory: 6G
- VMware: 7.1.3 build-324285
- Ubuntu: ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you accidentally downloaded the server iso of ubuntu rather than the desktop iso. You can install the default desktop installation on server by typing "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" in the terminal. It's going to take a while to download.

Comment: It shows that "ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version." and did not process anything...